# How to fix this GetInfo() method in Data Access Layer using LINQ-To-Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to use LINQ to Entities in my DAL. I am struggling now with GetInfo() method that I want it to retrieve all the items' information from Items Entity as a List. Then, I can bind the list to the GridView. The problem that the Visual Studio keeps giving me a red line under the following linq statement in GetInfo() method:

```
return selectQuery.ToList();
```

**GetInfo() Method Code:**

```
public class Item
{
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }



    public Item()
    {

    }

    public List<Item> GetInfo()
    {
        using (Entities entities = new Entities())
        {
            IEnumerable<item> selectQuery = (from item in entities.Items
                              orderby item.ID
                              select new {item.ID.ToString()};
            return selectQuery.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**So how I can fix this method in my DAL?**

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't select out an `item`; it selects out a new anonymous object that has a single string property with the item value.  If you want to return a list of items you'll need to just `select item` instead of the select statement that you have.  If you want to just select the ID then you should instead `select item.ID` and change the return type of the query to `IEnumerable<int>` or whatever the type of the ID is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, since I am new LINQ user, would you kindly provide me with an example and code snippet? I really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: @TechnologyLover I'm entirely confident in your ability to determine how to apply the code snippets I provided to your solution, with the assistance of the explanations surrounding those snippets.  On top of that, the error message (that you didn't even bother to provide in the question) is quite clear about what is wrong.  Don't just assume that because it's an error message it's a garbled mess, the C# compiler's error messages are on the whole very good.

Comment: What about if I want to retrieve more than one column?

Comment: @TechnologyLover Then you need to put those three columns into some type of object, and return that object.  Create a new class if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample to go with Servy's suggestion
You have a couple of things going on here:

1. It looks as though you want to return only the Item.Id, and not all of the columns
2. It looks as though you want to convert Item.Id to a string

To solve #1:
The problem is that since you are selecting a subset of customer (and an anonymous type), you are not returning an IEnumerable<Item>  it's an IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousType>

That's why you have a compile-time error.

So, Here's the first part (this would return a list of ints)

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetInfo()
{
   var query = from item in Entities.Items
               orderby item.Id
               select item.Id;
   return query.ToList();
}
```

(I'm selecting ints, so I'm returning an enumerable of ints)

Now, that's part of the issue, but you need for the items to be strings.  One important thing to know:  Any operator or function that you put onto your query before you make force the query to be enumerated will be part of the SQL.  The point where you are forcing your query to be enumerated (executed) is when you call ToList()

So, if I try to do:

```
select item.Id.ToString();
```

I'm going to have a problem, because Entity Framework is going to be looking for a ToString() function in SQL (you'll get an exception)

The operator that you want to use to do that is the Cast<> method

It looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetInfo()
{
   var query = from item in Entities.Items
               orderby item.Id
               select item.Id;
   return query.Cast<string>();
}
```

As an aside, if you are just learning linq and ef, I would highly recommend that you try out LinqPad -- it's a great way to play around with this stuff.

One more note bear in mind that if you use the Cast() function, it changes teh SQL that you send to the server to this:

```
SELECT
 CAST( [c].[CustomerId] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [c]
```

If you leave out the Cast(), then SQL server doesn't have to do the conversion (but you get back ints, not strings, assuming Item.Id is an int):

```
SELECT
[c].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId]
FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [c]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I want to retrieve three columns. Does you solution work with that, too?

Comment: Works almost the same way -- if you want to return it that collection of 3 columns from your method, you will need to define a class that has those three columns in it, make your method return an IEnumerable<theClass>, and then in your select, use new theClass {propertyName = c.TheColumn, property2Name = c.TheSecondColumn } etc